# Использование ссылок в квадратном уравнении С++

Tags: c++, функции, ссылки

Помогите новичку разобраться. Нужно сделать функцию для решения квадратного уравнения. Функция должна возвращать кол-во корней или -1, если уравнение  имеет бесконечное множество решений. Функция должна поучить коэффициенты в качестве аргументов и возвращать корни как аргументы-ссылки. 
Первую часть я реализовал, функция считает ко-во корней в зависимости от дискриминанта. Теперь с помощью ссылок нужно вывести эти корни. Но как это сделать?

```
    #include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;

int kvad(double a, double b, double c) {
double d = (b*b) - (4 * a*c);
if (d == 0) {
    return 1;
}
if (d > 0) {
    return 2;
}
if (a == 0 && b == 0 && c == 0) {
    return -1;
}
if (d<0) {
    return 0;
}
}

int main() {
double a, b, c;
cout << "Enter a: " << endl;
cin >> a;
cout << "Enter b:" << endl;
cin >> b;
cout << "Enter c:" << endl;
cin >> c;
cout <<"Kol-vo kornei: "<< kvad(a, b, c) << endl;
return 0;
}
```

Comment: для реализации такой штуки, вам нельзя использовать double.
потому что как только аргументы будут вида 1/3, оно начнет давать неверные результаты

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Измените объявление функции на

```
int kvad(double a, double b, double c, double& r1, double& r2)
```

Внутри функции вычислите значения r1 и r2.

При вызове функции надо будет указать еше две переменные типа double, которые примут значения корней.

Answer (score 0):

Для мнимой части корня ещё четыре параметра

```
int kvad(double a, double b, double c, double& rr1, double& ri1, double& rr2, double& ri2)
```